# Swift ios with Soap Wcf Web service

Tags: ios, swift

Can anybody help on connecting issue swift ios with soap object

```
  var soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'><soap:Body> <BindCategory xmlns=‘http://tempuri.org/'></BindCategory></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"


        var urlString = "http://assetwebservice.sudesi.in/service.svc"

        var msgLength = String(count(soapMessage))
        var url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

        var theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue("http://tempuri.org/IService/BindCategory", forHTTPHeaderField: "Soapaction")
        theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)


        var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self,startImmediately: true)
        connection?.start()

        if (connection == true) {
            println("Connection success")
            var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
        }else{
            println("Error in connection")
        }
```

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't state what the issue is by updating your post.

Comment: What is `var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()`? I can't make heads or tails of that.

Comment: Also, I think the best way to make your connection a rousing success is to dump SOAP and use REST instead, though I realize you may not have that option. 

Answer (score 2):

Well, the thing that jumps out at me is the following:

```
if (connection == true) {
    println("Connection success")
    // What does this line mean? I can't make sense of it.
    var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
}
```

You are comparing an `NSURLConnection?` to a `Bool`. This is never going to be true. Besides, this is not the correct way to determine whether a connection is successful. `NSURLConnection` has an optional initializer so that it can check whether its parameters are valid, not so that the success of a connection can be determined. Success will be determined by the appropriate callbacks to the delegate.

You should look into using `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection` unless you have to support iOS < 7.0, which I doubt. I have a suspicion—perhaps false—that the questioner is a C# programmer doing Swift who is perhaps not familiar with the delegate pattern, which is common in Apple's frameworks but not common at all in Microsoft's. If so, `NSURLSession`'s interface will be much more palatable.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in soap envevlope mapping , now I have correct that  , all things are now perfect.

Thanks

Comment: can you please tell me how you resolve the problems? I faced the same issues too. Thanks